# I need help implementing Bearer Token in my API code but I don't know how :(

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wrote the code for my API but I didn't wrote the code for the Bearer Token since I don't know how to do it properly since I am new to swift :) so if anyone could help me or reference me to a link on how to do it :)

This Is all I have about it in my code but its not working :(

```
                let headers = [
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "authorizetoken": "NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjA0QUY0NjVENkE=",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                ]
    
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 120)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
```

Comment: if you able  to use Alamofire pod then i can easily tell you

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed yes I will just guide me please

Comment: If you know what the bearer authorization is, what you have shown does not quite make sense.

Comment: @L1S i posted the answer bellow check if it works otherwise let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation
func ApiCall(urlString:String,completion:@escaping (_ data:Data?,_ error:Error?)->Void) {
   let url = URL(string: urlString)!

   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorizetoken": "NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjA0QUY0NjVENkE=",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            ]
//// you can write "Bearer" if you are requesting url as a user from server like its only use for you 
////if not only for you but for a group of users or for an app you shold only wirte the token string


URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
  guard error == nil else { return completion(nil,error) }

  guard let data = data, let response = response else { return }
  let yourdata = data
  completion(data,nil)
  print(data,response)
  // handle data
}.resume()


}
```

and you can use it like

```
let data = ApiCall(urlString:"http:example.com") { data, error in
  if let _data = data {
 // handle your data here 
    }
  if let err = error {
 // handle your error here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your allHTTPHeaderFields

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorizetoken": "Bearer NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjA0QUY0NjVENkE=",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            ]
```

Comment: "authorizetoken": "Bearer NjQzODM2N0NDNDM4NDhCNDk3RkU0NjA0QUY0NjVENkE="         So I gotta leave the Bearer in "" or remove it

Comment: // you can write "Bearer" if you are requesting url as a user from server like its only use for you 
// if not only for you but for a group of users or for an app you shold only wirte the token string

Comment: @L1S i have updated my answer and you can check that